# Add target blank on base64 link encoded

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, encryption, base64

I have a base64 system on my wordpress site to encrypt link. All works like a charm but i just want to open this link in a target blank.

This code encrypt my link and decrypt it after.

I dont know how to do this. Do you any idea to add "target _blank ?

Link in my post

```
<span class="lc" data="<?php echo cl(get_field(lien)); ?>" onclick="test()"> link </span></div>
```

I generate link with ACF plugin

JS

```
function btob(text) {
   text = text.replace(/\s/g,""); if (!(/^[a-z0-9\+\/\s]+\={0,2}$/i.test(text)) || text.length % 4 > 0) { return text; }
   var digits = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/', cur, prev, digitNum, i=0, result = [], text = text.replace(/=/g, "");
   while (i < text.length){
       cur = digits.indexOf(text.charAt(i)); digitNum = i++ % 4;
       switch (digitNum) {
           case 1: result.push(String.fromCharCode(prev << 2 | cur >> 4)); break;
           case 2: result.push(String.fromCharCode((prev & 0x0f) << 4 | cur >> 2)); break;
           case 3: result.push(String.fromCharCode((prev & 3) << 6 | cur)); break;
       }
       prev = cur;
   }
   return result.join('');
}

function transformText() {
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        if ((s[i].className.indexOf('lc') != -1)) {
            var lien = btob(s[i].getAttribute('data')).replace(/ajoutdunechainedecaractere/g,"");
            var lnk = document.createElement('a'); 
            lnk.href = lien; 
            lnk.innerHTML = s[i].innerHTML; 
            s[i].innerHTML = ''; 
            s[i].appendChild(lnk);

            if( s[i].hasAttribute("onclick") ) {
                //on récupère l'attribut onclick pour l'ajouter dans le lien
               lnk.setAttribute('onclick', s[i].getAttribute('onclick'));
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload=transformText;
```

function php

```
// crypt
function cl($url) {
    $taille = strlen($url);
    $urlcode = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $taille; $i++) {
        if ($i % 2) {
            $urlcode.= "ajoutdunechainedecaractere" . $url{$i};
        } else {
            $urlcode.= $url{$i};
        }
    }
    return base64_encode($urlcode);
}
```

Comment: Base64 encoding should not be confused with encryption. Anyone can decode the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
lnk.target = "_blank";
```

But I am not sure what the final URL is. Dealing with the URL on a separate window could be harder. The main catch is with `test()` which is added in case `<span>` has `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the target="_blank" to the html element.

```
...
lnk.href = lien; 
lnk.target = "_blank";
...
```